New to gradle. Cannot find the proper gradle.build for eclipse. to load dependencies and build
I am trying to get JCSG and all it's dependencies into an eclipse java project.  I've asked Google and Chatgpt how to set it up and they all give different values for the gradle dependency to pull it all in.  They all fail with unresolved dependency.  Has anyone done this and how did you do it?
I tried multiple domains and multiple versions with something like this for build.gradle:
plugins { 
  id 'java'
}

repositories { 
  mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies { 
  implementation 'com.github.miho:jcsg:2.1.0'
}

Note: sorry for the formatting, the form would not let me include it with the proper spacing for some reason.

Well the dependency you added isn't in Maven Central, so obviously it won't be resolved from there. There is some 0.5 version available so not sure what version or dependency you are trying to download.

The latest version of that dependency seems to be 0.5.7: https://github.com/miho/JCSG/releases

I tried 0.5.7 and got the same results.  What is the correct location of the dependency?

Is com.github.miho:jcsg:2.1.0 from ChatGPT? There is eu.mihosoft.vrl.jcsg:jcsg:0.5.7 in Maven Central, but I don't know if that's the dependency you're really looking for.

The repository README would seem to indicate you are meant to compile and assemble the jar yourself.

It seemed to work with eu.mihosoft.vrl.jcsg:jcsg:0.5.7 and loaded the jar files into the project but it didn't pull in some of the other jars it references like JavaFX.  I'm trying to find the scraps now.
